# racket: counting number of siblings

Tags: list, tree, nested, racket, siblings

Having nested lists as the input, I'm trying to find how to output the number of 'siblings' an element has. In terms of trees, how many other leaf nodes belong to the same parent/root node.

My code is giving the wrong outputs (it's a really bad code) and I'm not sure how to entirely approach the question

```
(define (siblings lst n)
 (cond
     [(empty? lst) false]
     [(member? n lst) (sub1 (length lst))]
     [else (siblings (rest lst) n)]))
```

sample outcomes: if given (list (list 2 1) 3 (list 4)) and 3, produce 0

(list (list 1 2 3) (list (list 4 5 6 ))) and 5 -> 2

Comment: Post a few examples with their expected output.

Comment: `member?` does not exist in the `#!racket` language. There are `member`, `memv`, and `memq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has to do two separate things:

1. Find the branch that contains *n*
2. Count the number of siblings in that branch, accounting for the possibility of other branches starting there.

Finding the branch that contains *n*, assuming that *n* can only appear once:

```
(define (find-branch root n)
  (cond ((empty? root) empty)
        ((memq n root)
          root)
        ((list? (first root))
         (let ((subresult (find-branch (first root) n)))
           (if (not (empty? subresult))
               subresult
               (find-branch (rest root) n))))
        (else (find-branch (rest root) n))))
```

Since you're using "Beginning Student," that takes all the tools out of your toolbox. Fortunately, it still has `number?`, so if it's safe to assume that anything that isn't a number in this assignment is a list, you can define `list?` like this:

```
(define (list? n) (not (number? n)))
```

Given your example tree as input, it would return:

```
(4 5 6)
```

The above example unnecessarily uses `memq` repeatedly on the `rest` of the
input list as a result of using recursion to iterate over the same list.

Here's a more efficient version of the above, but you can't implement it in Beginning Student:

```
(define (find-branch root n)
  (cond ((empty? root) false)
        ((memq n root) root)
        (else (foldl (λ (a b)
                        (if (empty? a) b a))
                     empty
                     (map (λ (sublist)
                             (find-branch sublist n))
                       (filter list? root))))))
```

You pass the result of that to a function to count the siblings. I previously provided a version that would work in the real Racket, but not the Beginning Student version used by teachers:

```
(define (count-siblings root mem)
  (count (λ (sib)
            (and (not (eq? sib mem))
                 (not (list? sib)))) root))
```

Here's a version that's compatible with Beginning Student:

```
(define (count-siblings lst n counter)
  (cond
     [(empty? lst) counter]
     [(and (not (list? (first lst)))
           (not (eq? n (first lst)))) 
      (count-siblings (rest lst) n (add1 counter))]
     [else (count-siblings (rest lst) n counter)]))
```

Finally, put the two together:

```
(define (find/count-siblings root n)
   (count-siblings (find-branch root n) n 0))
```

Comment: I'm currently using beginner's language, is there any way to write that without the  local definition or list?

Comment: `(define (list? n) (not (number? n)))` that gives you a version of `list?` that should be good enough for this assignment (but it'll give wrong results if you use it in an assignment that includes strings, symbols, or whatever else is allowed in Beginning Student). I've rewritten `count-siblings` and `find/count-siblings` to account for the lack of local definitions.